# Where does this extra space comes from?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/FqW4R/ and on the picture below, my menu items are not perfectly aligned with "logo" and "social". Also there's a massive gap between the menu categories (Menu I, Menu 2, etc) and the sub-items. When I look at my code I do not see extra padding or anything like that that could cause this type of issue. Any thoughts on that? Many thanks

[image]

```
Html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* mainmenu */

#mainmenu {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mainmenu ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
}
#mainmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
#mainmenu>ul>li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#mainmenu ul li a, #mainmenu ul ul:hover li a {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}
#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover, #mainmenu ul ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #005EBC;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in, linear, ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -o-transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    transition-duration: .4s, .4s, .4s, .4s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all, -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: all, -moz-transform;
    -ms-transition-property: all, -ms-transform;
    -o-transition-property: all, -o-transform;
    transition-property: all, transform;
}

#social {
position: absolute;
    float:right;
    right: 10px;
    Color: blue;
    margin-top: 35px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="logo">Logo</div>  <!-- End DIV Logo -->
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu I</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Biography</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Publications</a> </li>
        </ul>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 2</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Demo</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Features</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Comparison</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 3</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 1</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 2</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">Item 3</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h5>Menu 4</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a title="" href="">ddfd</a> </li>
          <li><a title="" href="">dsfd</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  <!-- End DIV Main Menu -->
 <div id="social">Social</div><!-- End DIV Social -->
```

Comment: Have you looked at your DOM inspection tools yet?

Comment: Hi - how do I do that? Tks

Comment: Depends on which browser, but a DOM inspector tool is built into most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use a CSS Reset, because if you don't reset the elements, browser will apply some default styles to your elements, which you don't want eh? You can Google out, will get tons out there, if you want to keep it simply but you want to reset, you can use the below block of code and paste it in your CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqW4R/2/) (Reduced spacing)

It seems like you should learn positioning, you are using `position: absolute;` element, without wrapping the element inside `position: relative;` container, this way, your `position: absolute;` elements will flow out in the wild. Also, I don't think you want to use `absolute`, using `float` will be appropriate here.

See how the positioning matters..

[What you are doing](http://jsfiddle.net/hBJR3/)

[What should you do](http://jsfiddle.net/hBJR3/1/) (Saw `position: relative;` there?)

The horizontal space between each menu is caused because you are using explicit `width`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqW4R/5/)

Also, if you use `float`, you don't require `display: inline-block;`

---

I suggest you to learn [CSS Positioning](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) and [Floats](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101)

Answer (score 1):

You should read about the CSS Box model. Further to this you are using position:absolute: which actually creates the problem when you resize the screen. Properly use of floats is important to layout the site. I just fixed some of these issues for you and **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FqW4R/6/)** is the reworked menu.

Hope this helps.

A little of my rewritten CSS is below.

```
#social {
border:1px solid green;
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    Color: blue;

}

#mainmenu {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}


#logo {
    float:left;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    border:1px solid black;

    width:150px;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/FqW4R/6/**

Comment: Thanks defau1t. Understand from other people answers that using "float" as you did is a cleaner way compared to what I did. Question though: with your suggested code the 3 DIVs are LEFT-aligned next to each other. However what I would like is the logo DIV to be aligned to  the left side of the screen and Mainmenu + social DIVs to be aligned to the right side. I tried "float: right" to main menu and social but that did not work. Any thoughts? Many thanks

Comment: I tried to wrap my social DIV within my main menu DIV and added "position: absolute;" to the CSS code of #social. It worked but not sure if this is the best way. It's now positioned to the right of the menu.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, that is not a valid and recommended approach. you would also need to reorder social and main menu divs in your markup. It is like writing your English language from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Your `h5` elements have margins on them.  To fix, simply place this in your CSS:

```
h5 {
    margin:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/FqW4R/1/

Answer (score 0):

Also on jsfiddle, you can use the [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) feature provided to reset the defaults.

To access it, look on the left pane, click `Fiddle Options` and tick `Normalized CSS` and then hit `Run` to view your updated code.